# To extract a certain value in a directory path using tcl

Tags: tcl

Intend to extract a value of a directory path using tcl. The directory path looks like this:

```
C:\working\636-3419-3\S80\FILE
```

The directory path will not always the same due to different users on different PC, some are:

```
C:\Users\name\351-3100-11\Desktop
Z:\backup\S70\721Z3121-3\FILE
```

I need to extract the value (`636-3419-3` or `351-3100-11` ...these numbers are always different) and set as a variable (`mom_number`) which later I use it (`$mom_number`).

I tried to split the path on the slash, it works, but for other cases, I don't know how to get the number value out only. Please help with example of the codes. Thanks a lot.

Here are the code I write which only can extract 636.....

```
set mom_pn_number $mom_part_name
# Separate data with the character "\"
set pn_num [split $mom_pn_number \\]
# To search for the number from the separated data
set pn_number [lsearch -inline $pn_num 636*]
set mom_part_number $pn_number
```

(The `$mom_part_name` is the full directory path), I don't know whether the if and else statement will works, but always came with errors.

The numbers can came in any type from 0 to 9, is like serial numbers of different products. I try split the path using `[split $mom_pn_number \\]` and it works with the output separated by white space.

As for

```
C:\Users\name\351-3100-11\Desktop
```

My intention result is `351-3100-11`.

If some users save their files on some other directory as example below:

```
Z:\backup\S70\721Z3121-3\FILE
```

My intention result is `721Z3121-3`.

Thanks

Comment: If you add your code, it really helps everbody.

Comment: Also, what is common with the numbers? Are they always "number-number-number"? Can they appear more than once in a single path and if they do, do you always need the first instance?

Comment: What is in common between `C:\Users\name\351-3100-11\Desktop` and `Z:\backup\S70\721Z3121-3\FILE`? The former appears to match the "636-3419-3 or 351-3100-11..." you present but what should be extracted out of `Z:\backup\S70\721Z3121-3\FILE`?

Comment: And another random note: consider using `[file split $pathname]` -- it works in a predictable cross-platform way.

Comment: Without more restrictive rules for the product number, it's close to impossible to get what you want. Are there any minimum length of the product code? The example you gave with Z: has a product code with a letter, which doesn't match the part you mention "I don't know how to get the number value out only"...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `split` for filenames. Use `file split` (as it handles a bunch of tricky cases) on the normalized name (to prevent ugly surprises). Then use `lsearch` with the right pattern; this one happens to be easier to express with a regular expression.

```
set items [file split [file normalize $mom_part_name]]
set mom_part_number [lsearch -inline -regexp $items {^[-0-9]+$}]
```

The key is that it assumes that all part numbers are digits and dashes, and if you want dashes in a RE character set then you have to put them first.

Comment: Thanks, it works and solve my problem. How about if I need to search for specify character? Like my post example C:\Users\name\351-3100-11\Desktop and Z:\backup\S70\721Z3121-3\FILE, I need to extract "Desktop" and "backup", what should be the code after the $items {^.....]. As can see you teach me is -0-9 as range, now I have list of 6 directory path and my this tcl just run on individual PC.

Answer (score 0):

For the `C:\Users\name\XYZ-nnnn-nn\Desktop` style pathnames do

```
set fname {C:\Users\name\XYZ-nnnn-nn\Desktop}
set nns [lindex [file split $fname] 3]

set pn_number [lindex [split $nns -] 0]
```

If you really want to rely on finding the first path component which starts with a digit, just do that:

```
set parts [file split $fname]
set pix [lsearch -glob $parts {[0-9]*}]
set pn_number [lindex [split [lindex $parts $pix] -] 0]
```

That is,

1. Split the filename into parts (`Z:\`, `blah`, …).
2. Find the index of the first element starting with any decimal digit.
3. Use that index to get the actual element (`lindex`),
   then `split` it on `-`s, and take the first one (`lindex` again).

Comment: I will try tomorrow, now office going to close. By the way, thanks a lot for the codes written by u as I try for weeks, using trimleft or trimright.....Is the second option that u wrote is the case I want.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
set pattern {.*\\(([0-9A-Z]+-?)*)\\.*}
set foo {C:\Users\name\351-3100-11\Desktop}
set bar {Z:\backup\S70\721Z3121-3\FILE}

set result [regexp -inline -all -- $pattern $foo]
if {[llength $result] > 0} {
    puts "foo::$foo -> [lindex $result 1]"
}

set result [regexp -inline -all -- $pattern $bar]
if {[llength $result] > 0} {
    puts "bar::$bar -> [lindex $result 1]"
}
```

**Execution output:**

```
foo::C:\Users\name\351-3100-11\Desktop -> 351-3100-11
bar::Z:\backup\S70\721Z3121-3\FILE -> 721Z3121-3
```

Answer (score -1):

Below code is working. Check.
SBORDOLO-M-V1VG:EXPERIMENT sbordolo$ vi t5

```
 set a {C:\working\636-3419-3\S80\FILE}
 set b {C:\Users\name\351-3100-11\Desktop Z:\backup\S70\721Z3121-3\FILE}

 foreach line [list $a $b] {
 if {[regexp -- "(\[0-9\]+\[-\]\[0-9\]+\[-\]\[0-9\]+)" $line - dir]} {
     puts "yes: $dir"
 } else {
     puts "not matched"
 }   
 }
```

SBORDOLO-M-V1VG:EXPERIMENT sbordolo$

```
  tclsh t5
  yes: 636-3419-3
  yes: 351-3100-11
```

Comment: I solved my case by the help of Donal Fellows. set items [file split [file normalize $mom_part_name]]
set mom_part_number [lsearch -inline -regexp $items {^[-0-9]+$}]